# How to Close the Thread?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at the following threads that I started:

[Microsoft Web Platfrom Installer Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614025/microsoft-web-platfrom-installer-error)

[ASP.NET Website Administrator Tool in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798880/asp-net-website-administrator-tool-in-vs-2013)

I have found the answers to this threads. So how can I mark them as answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You can press "delete" yourself.

Comment: Means?? I am not getting. We need to keep the thread if someone needs answer for the same question. I just need to mark as answer.

Comment: These are questions you asked, not threads you started - we're not a forum; we don't have threads.

Comment: I did what you suggested. As soon as I marked as answer someone did vote down. That was the reason I was asking can we post our answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can answer your own question, just write it as if you were another user who solved your problem. This is allowed, you can read about it in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

There is a button on the bottom for this:
[image]

Comment: Is that allowed???

Comment: @Jatin sure, allowed and even encouraged behavior.

Comment: @Jatin If it wasn't allowed, you wouldn't see the button.

Comment: I did what you suggested. As soon as I marked as answer someone did vote down. That was the reason I was asking can we post our answer.

Comment: @Jatin You are allowed to do this. **It is written in the official Help Center**. The reason why you were downvoted was probably because the **quality** of the answer you provided was low. For example you provided a [link only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1

You can leave your answer to your own questions. This is preferable in my opinion. So that others who have the same question that you posted, can then see what your solution was when you leave an answer.

Option 2

You can delete it yourself, but I don't recommend this option.

Comment: Ya option 1 is what I was asking. But for that I will have to post it as answer right. Right now i have posted answers as a comment.

Comment: I did what you suggested. As soon as I marked as answer someone did vote down. That was the reason I was asking can we post our answer.